# How to highlight jsTree node?

Tags: jquery, css, class, jstree

I want to trigger click event of my jsTree node. The code i have written bellow does it. My problem is that after the event is triggered the node does not get highlighted.

```
$("#myTreeId li[id=" + myLiId + "] a").click();
$("#myTreeId li[id=" + myLiId + "] a").addClass('jstree-clicked');
```

How can i do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can the jstree function `selectNode`; using it is triggered the function `select_node.jstree` binded.

Code:

```
$("#tree").jstree("select_node", "#30");
```

The id used as second parameter is the id attribute used to fill each node of the tree; clearly the data that you use to fill the tree must include an id attribute.

Code sample:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "data": [{
            "data": "pe_opensourcescanning",
                "attr": {
                "id": 77,
                    "pId": -1
            },
                "children": [{
                "data": "tags",
                    "attr": {
                    "id": 30,
                        "pid": 0
                }
            }, {
                "data": {
                    "title": "branches"
                },
                    "attr": {
                    "id": 29,
                        "pid": 0
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
})

$("#tree").bind(
    "select_node.jstree", function (evt, data) {
    console.log('select!');
});

$("#selectNode").click(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree("select_node", "#30");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/UE9Ed/

Comment: select_node also works fine(the node is selected) but still not highlighted

Comment: If you check the demo on jsfiddle the node is highlighted, is your css complete?

Comment: yeah, your code works great. yeah i think my css is complete. may be the problem is that i call open_node function then select_node?